# Generic types lose their Generic[T, ...] base class in the .pyi file generated by stubgen

Tags: python, generics, types, mypy

Let's say there is a very simple class that represents a generic stack and hence is inherited from `Generic[T]` (***§1***).

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, List

T = TypeVar('T')

class Stack(Generic[T]): #1
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.items: List[T] = []

    def push(self, item: T) -> None:
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self) -> T:
        return self.items.pop()

    def empty(self) -> bool:
        return not self.items
```

And then let's generate a stub file `.pyi` for the module in which the `Stack` class lies, say, `stack.py`:

```sh
$ stubgen stack.py --output stubs
```

It's obvious that the `Generic[T]` base class was unexpectedly stripped off (***§2***). Meanwhile, the type hint for the `items` property was replaced as `Any` (***§3***). Additionally, what makes things more weird is that the stubbed versions of both `push` and `pop` still bore the type hint `T` for the parameter and the return value respectively (***§4*** and ***§5***).

```py
from typing import Any, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class Stack: #2
    items: Any = ... #3
    def __init__(self) -> None: ...
    def push(self, item: T) -> None: ... #4
    def pop(self) -> T: ... #5
    def empty(self) -> bool: ...
```

What happened during the generation of the stub? Is there any explanation to justify such a behavior?

P.S. My `mypy` version is 0.790.

Comment: The stubgen docs explicitly say that the stubs are drafts and heavily use ``Any``: ["Stubgen generates draft stubs. The auto-generated stub files often require some manual updates, and most types will default to Any. The stubs will be much more useful if you add more precise type annotations, at least for the most commonly used functionality."](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubgen.html)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thank you for your response. But in fact what confuses me in this case is 
the absence of the `Generic[T]` base class in the stubbed `Stack`'s inheritance list.